Options for connecting bare cord light
Have a few led flood lights similar to this one as pictured, Amazon review below

These come with a yoke and a not easily replaceable bare wire appliance cord. What options would I have in the US to wire these up, aside from adding a standard plug?
Canopy cover plate + round junction box? Cable gland + 1/2 knockout plate? Grommet + diy hole in blank metal plate/box?

Are these rated for outdoor use? Do you intend to use them outdoors?

I don’t see a UL sticker on it. Return it and buy something that won’t burn your house down. And don’t buy it from Amazon.

@jimmy questionably rated for outdoor (ip66) but no, don't intend to use them outdoors.

You can save a lot of money on your house insurance by showing that to them.  I expect a 100% savings.

@crip659 insurance pulled policy when they saw 3 leaves on the roof with a drone. Can we cut back on the sky is falling though?

@cde - your insurance company requires you to use approved equipment. That is why Underwriters Laboratory exists, and why the National Fire Protection Association is the body that sets National Electrical Code. All in the hopes that your house doesn’t burn down so the insurance companies don’t have to pay out (or your insurance would be more expensive).

@joncuster no insurance policy, see previous comment.

So you are doubling down on installing crap. Fair enough…

Unless adding a plug on the end, you will need a junction box of some type to cover the wire splices.  I believe most boxes require some type of wire clamp to hold the wire in the box, so a simple grommet is probably not enough.
